# Configure Secret Key with bash commands

Tags: python, bash

I am trying the code from this [snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/104/). But is not working.

What I am getting is:

```
Error: No secret key. Create it with:
mkdir -p /home/xxx/Documents/AptanaStudio3Workspace/instance
head -c 24 /dev/urandom > /home/xxx/Documents/AptanaStudio3Workspace/instance/secret_key
```

Seems like the bash commands are not executed, because there isn't a folder called instance.

---

```
########################
# Configure Secret Key #
########################
def install_secret_key(app, filename='secret_key'):
    filename = os.path.join(app.instance_path, filename)
    try:
        app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = open(filename, 'rb').read()
    except IOError:
        print 'Error: No secret key. Create it with:'
        if not os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(filename)):
            print 'mkdir -p', os.path.dirname(filename)
        print 'head -c 24 /dev/urandom >', filename
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python command is `print` and it is getting executed, as is visible from the output you posted.

Apparently you expected the script to actually run those commands for you, but it's not attempting to do that.

The error message should properly be printed to standard error, and of course, the script could be extended to actually run those commands instead of just printing an error message.